# Access the state of store or getters? _WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__store___.a.dispatch is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I am trying to verify if the user is authenticated to be able to give access to the route that is directed otherwise redirect to the login route, the problem is that I do not know how to execute the `fetchUser` action from my `beforeEach`. In other words, I can't access my **getter from the router** script.

**store.js**

```
import mutations from './mutations';
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';

export default {
    state: {
        isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
        user_data : localStorage.getItem("user_data"),
    },
    getters ,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import routes from './rutas';
import store from '../store/';
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode : 'history',
  routes 
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn)  {
            next({path: '/login'})
        }
        else {
            store.dispatch('fetchUser') // Line error
            next()
        }
    } 
    else {
        next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }
})
```

**getters.js**

```
export default {
    isLoggedIn: state => {
        return state.isLoggedIn
    },
    user_name  : state =>{
        if(! _.isEmpty(this.user_data))
            return JSON.parse(state.user_data).name
        return '';
    },
    isEmptyUser : state =>{
        return  _.isEmpty(this.user_data);
    },
    isAdmin: state => {
        if(! _.isEmpty(this.user_data)) return state.user_data.nivel===1
        return false;
    }
}
```

**actions.js**

```
 export default {
 /* more methods*/

 , async fetchUser({ commit }) {
    return await axios.post('/api/auth/me')
        .then(res => {   
            setTimeout(() => {
                localStorage.setItem("user_data", JSON.stringify(res.data)); 
                Promise.resolve(res.data); 
            }, 1000);             
        },
        error => {                  
            Promise.reject(error);          
        });
}
```

This returns error in console:

> _WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__store___.a.dispatch is not a function

How can I do or the approach is the wrong one and I should not access actions directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `store` is not the actual store object, it is just the object used to generate it.

A solution is to have the file export the real store:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import mutations from './mutations';
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';

Vue.use(Vuex); // added here
export default new Vuex.Store({  // changed here
    state: {
        isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
        user_data : localStorage.getItem("user_data"),
    },
    getters ,
    mutations,
    actions
})  // changed here
```

Now your router code would work.

What you must be aware as well is that somewhere, probably in your main.js, you had the store being initialized like above. For example:

```js
import store from '../store/';
new Vue({
  store: new Vuex.Store(store),
  // ...
})
```

Now you must remove that initialization and use the store directly:

```js
import store from '../store/';
new Vue({
  store: store, // or simply store
  // ...
})
```

And all should be good.

Comment: In the instance of Vue I have `store: new Vuex.Store (store)`, as mentioned but when I do this I receive the error call *Vue.use (Vuex) before creating a store instance*. and if I do the typical `Vue.use (Vuex)`  I get the error *getters should be function but "getters.isLoggedIn" is true*

Comment: Can you paste your getters declaration in the question?

Comment: Did you get that error before changing? everything was working fine but the router, before?

Comment: It works fine now, just a short question, is it possible to add a getter in mapState? I have now added a new field in data and grab `username : this.$store.getters.user_name,`

Comment: I'm assuming you use `mapState` to create computed properties from the state. Similarly, you can use `mapGetters` to create computed properties from getters. Is that it?

Comment: yes but by adding mapState together and ... mapGetters inside computed throw me syntax error , `computed : {
   ...mapGetters([
    'user_data',
    'isEmptyUser',
    'isAdmin'
      ]),
   mapState(['isLoggedIn','user_data'])
  },`

Comment: Use `...` in both: `computed : { ...mapGetters([ 'user_data', 'isEmptyUser', 'isAdmin' ]), ...mapState(['isLoggedIn','user_data']) }`

Comment: Thank you very much for the patience, I would like to give you more points but good thanks.